# Xcode 6 ad hoc distribution over url

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode 6 wont let me build my app for enterprise distribution. In Xcode 5 I would simply export my archive and select enterprise so I could enter a url.  Xcode 6 gives me this error if I export for enterprise:

[image]

I already paid my 99 dollar subscription fee so whats the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like Apple has removed this feature to generate the .plist needed for enterprise distribution from the archive process for developers that don't have an enterprise account.  What you should be able to do is modify one of the  .plist files generated by the last version of Xcode and use that to point to the URL where you  will host your new .ipa file.  Don't know why Apple would have removed this feature from the archive process, but it could have something to do with their push to better accommodate the enterprise market.

Comment: Thanks. So an Enterprise account isn't the same as my current subscription to develop iOS apps? The 99 dollar a year subscription.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You need to enroll in the Apple Enterprise developer program, which is $299 a year and has special requirements. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: Yes this is very annoying that Apple have removed this option - I can see no reason at all for them to do this. I can confirm that exporting the ipa file as an ordinary ad hoc distribution, and then modifying the plist that you have from xcode 5 does still work as expected.

Comment: I created a gist of a Manifest plist template to use if you don't have one from xcode 5. Just fill in the details as mentioned. Find it here:  https://gist.github.com/74monkeys/13aec76b39c030dde9a5

Comment: I think it's because of the TestFlight integration. Apple wants its developer to use that to distribute the apps.